# iPodMusicPlayer's bug under ios 6.0.1?

Tags: ios, audio

I use [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setting the ipod volumn before playing a local "beep.caf" file which use AVAudioPlayer.
Strange things happened, if I kill the system ipod app before running the following code, the beep.caf played just 1~2 second which should be a 30 second audio.
The code like this:

```
self.ipodPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController ipodMusicPlayer];
self.ipodPlayer.volumn = .5;

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: fileName];

NSError *err = nil;
self.trackPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&err];
if(err)
{
     //LOG ERR
}
else
{
     if ([trackPlayer prepareToPlay]) {
          if (![trackPlayer play]) {
               //ALog(@"Error:play sound failed.");
          }
     }
     else
     {
          //ALog(@"Error:prepare play sound failed.");
     };
}
```

This code works well under iOS4.3. I doubt if there is something special done when the iPodMusicPlayer init under iOS 6.0.1.

I need to set ipodPlayer's volumn before play local audio, how can I do this correctly?